# XQuery - Join query

Tags: xml, join, xquery

I have two XML files and want to join them to get the desired output.

XML File -1

```
<Countries>
<Country>
   <No C="1"/>
   <Name>India</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
   <No C="2"/>
   <Name>USA</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
   <No C="3"/>
   <Name>Srilanka</Name>
</Country>
<Country>
   <No C="4"/>
   <Name>Thailand</Name>
</Country>
</Countries>
```

XML File - 2

```
<Capitals>
  <Capital>
      <No C="1"/>
      <Name>New Delhi</Name>
  </Capital>
  <Capital>
      <No C="2"/>
      <Name>Washington DC</Name>
  </Capital>
  <Capital>
      <No C="3"/>
      <Name>Colombo</Name>
  </Capital>
  <Capital>
      <No C="4"/>
      <Name>Bangkok</Name>
  </Capital>
</Capitals>
```

Output desired -

```
India - New Delhi
USA - Washington DC
Srilanka - Colombo
Thailand - Bangkok
```

What I have tried is like, but unable to get the desired output :(

```
for $x in doc('Country')/Countries
  return 
  <a>
 {$x/Country/Name}
 {
   for $y in doc('Capital')/Capitals
   where $y/Capital/No/@C = $x/Country/No/@C
    return $y/Capital/Name
  }
  </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer and it is -

TWO-Way Join in a Predicate -

```
for $x in doc('country')//Country
  return 
  string-join( ($x/Name/text(),  
     for $y in doc('capital')//Capital
       where $y/No/@C = $x/No/@C
       return $y/Name/text()
                ), " - ")
```

Comment: Note that the /text() is both unnecessary and bad practice (it causes the query to produce wrong results if there are comments in the source XML)

Comment: @MichaelKay- Thanks a lot for your valuable comment. Then what should be the best practice..?

Comment: If you want the content of element X as a string, then simply writing X is usually best; occasionally (if the context is not unambiguously a string context) you may need to use X/string().

Answer (score 2):

Your answer yields the correct results, however I find the following syntax (using XPath instead of another FLOWR expressions) much simpler:

```
for $x in doc('country')//Country
return 
  string-join( ($x/Name/text(),  
    $doc('capital')//Capital[./No/@C = $x/No/@C]/Name/text()
            ), " - ")
```